# Check condition for imbricated property in object

Tags: javascript

I want to use the following condition

```
if (this.solvedConflictsDetails[this.instance.instanceId][this.model.name][this.entity.entityId].solved)
```

The problem is that if one of the above doesn't exist in the object it will say cannot read undefined
How would you check a condition like this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I think you mean "nested", not "imbricated"